# Nginx Basic Authentication

Tags: nginx, authentication

I want to implement some basic authentication so that when I check my netdata dashboard at the domain it won't be wide open and viewable by everyone.

And I do have other apps I plan to run. Including ZNC which is already running.

Problem is that after I log into to the netdata subdomain, I cannot get into the znc web interface on another subdomain regardless of what password I put in.

Do I need to enable multiple log in sessions or is the native znc log in system making me unable to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found.

Add the line below if you are using nginx's basic auth module. Otherwise the nginx authentication header would be forwarded to the app,  which would cause all HTTP requests to fail. Adding the line also means that you can't access certain APIs via nginx with basic authentication

`proxy_set_header Authorization "";`